# mulithreading in android

Tags: android, multithreading

How to implement Multithreading in Android application so as to increase responsiveness of UI. ?

Comment: Are you talking about the Android UI or your application's UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UI in Android is already handled in a separate thread, so you don't need to worry about it. The faq has a section on [Handling Expensive Operations in the UI Thread](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#threading) if that is what you need to solve.

Comment: Will go through the link. Thanks

Comment: At line mHandler.post... Application is stopping unexpectely .

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to do some long and consuming task in the background so as not to lock the UI thread.

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) seems easier to use even though there are other approaches like using [runnables](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) and [handlers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

Answer (score 0):

Actors or similar event-based, managed lightweight threads are nice to treat UI events in a low-overhead fashion.